# R: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement

Tags: r, integer, digits

I am trying to split 2009 into 2 0 0 9.

```
int2v<-function(n){
+ digits<-floor(log10(n))+1
+ i<-1
+ repeat{
+ n[i]<-n%%10^(digits-i+1)%/%10^(digits-i)
+ i<-i+1
+ if(i>digits) break
+ }
+ n
+ }

> int2v(2009)
[1] 2 0 0 2
Warning messages:
1: In n[i] <- n%%10^(digits - i + 1)%/%10^(digits - i) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In n[i] <- n%%10^(digits - i + 1)%/%10^(digits - i) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I cannot get the answer 2 0 0 9 but have some warning message. 
But I can't think of any mistakes in the function. 
so, can any one help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you want `as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(2009), '')[[1]])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code

```
int2v<-function(n){
 digits<-floor(log10(n))+1
 i<-1
 n1 <- c()
 repeat{
  n1<-c(n1,n%%10^(digits-i+1)%/%10^(digits-i))
  i<-i+1
 if(i>digits) break
  }
 n1
 }


int2v(2009)
#[1] 2 0 0 9

int2v(20)
#[1] 2 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This can actually be done via built-in functions:

```
n<-2009
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(n),"")))
[1] 2 0 0 9
```

`as.character` converts the number `n` into a character string. `strsplit` splits the resulting string, with the second argument to `strsplit` making this split happen at every character. `unlist` collapses the list produced by `strsplit` into a vector, and `as.numeric` converts back to a numeric (rather than character) vector.

This won't work (obviously!) if `n` is not numeric to begin with ... you might want to test for this pre-condition if you wrap this code in a function. It's also worth noting that this won't work with a vector of numbers in `n`, because the `unlist` will collapse them all into one character string. But extending to these cases (if they are needed) shouldn't be too hard.